# What is test directory in GitHub Repositories in Frameworks like Foundation on GitHub?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, github, repository, automated-tests

I have seen a "test" directory in different responsive front-end framework projects? A typical example of the same would be Foundation's Test - https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/tree/develop/test/visual, Why do we need really it?
And What kind of test is really this - https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/test/visual/button/button.html

Answer (score 0):

These are directories for unit testing frameworks like Mocha, Chai and so on.
We also have visual regression tests to catch regressions produced by code changes.

Unit tests are meant to improve the overall code quality and automate testing on different platforms and in different browsers.